# in which/in how

Tags: relative-clauses, subordinate-clauses, interrogatives

> Spring Flower Gifts trains every manager in its retail stores in _______ they should deal with customer service.
>
> a. which
>
> b. who
>
> c. what
>
> d. how

The answer is d. I'd like to know why a. can't be correct.

Comment: None of the other options makes sense. The managers are being trained in _how_ (in what way) to serve their customers. (It's an odd sentence anyway; a native speaker would say simply _trains [them] in customer service_.)

Comment: @KateBunting But _Spring Flower Gifts trains every manager in its retail stores in which they should deal with customer service_ does make sense, because _in which they should deal with customer service_ can be a relative clause having _retail stores_ as its antecedent, doesn't it?

Comment: It's a cumbersome and unlikely sentence. I take the sentence to refer to _training in_ a skill rather than _in_ a place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's ignore the fact that the example sentence has problems; let's pretend it ends with "___ they should deal with customers."

Yes, (d) is the most likely answer simply because the meaning it creates makes the most sense. (a) could also be used in this sentence, but it creates a less likely meaning.

- *Spring Flower Gifts trains every manager in its retail stores in **how** they should deal with customers*: Here, the word "in" means "about," or "on the topic of." This means they "train them [about] **how**" they should deal with customers. They give them training "in" [the topic of] how to deal with them.
- *Spring Flower Gifts trains every manager in its retail stores in **which** they should deal with customer service*: Here, the word "in" forms a phrase along with "which," and suddenly the phrase *in which* modifies *stores*, completely changing the meaning. This means: They give training to some of their managers. Which managers? Those in certain stores. Which stores? Those stores **in which** the managers "should deal with customers." While this is grammatically possible, the meaning is less likely: Are there stores in which the managers "should not" deal with customers? Dealing with customers is often part of a store manager's job, and even if they don't *have* to, it's hard to imagine a company saying they *shouldn't*.

Comment: If the answer is (a), why not treat the prepositional phrase _in its retail stores...customer service_ as a temporal adjunct modifying the verb _trains_? That way, the relative clause _in which...customer service_ would provide necessary information about the place where they are trained.

Comment: @listeneva Good point, but for that meaning a comma is needed: "SPG trains every manager in its retail stores, in which they should deal with customer service." Without the comma, the clause starting with "in which" is [restrictive](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/using-that-and-which-is-all-about-restrictive-and-non-restrictive-clauses/?gclid=CjwKCAjw9LSSBhBsEiwAKtf0n-9MDoyGfWNIFlmLVjDp1UpJnfHJ7JAA_2CAT3m8xY-RJhNdrL-IuBoCSwcQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds); without it it's non-restrictive. (And the meaning would still be less likely; it would combine some unrelated concepts in one sentence.)

Comment: I don't understand why the relative clause cannot be restrictive in that reading. For example, every manager should be trained in their own retail store, not in any retail store.

Comment: @listeneva If you made "stores" into a singular that would be an option, sure. Or if "stores" stays plural, and "its" changes to "their," then perhaps we're describing managers who work in multiple stores but only train in one. But these meanings get more and more bizarre, and the more complicated they get, the more there are better phrasings to explain them.